# Use Last Method in Where Condition in LinQ to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

look at this code

```
IQueryable<Request> RequestsTotal = DataContext.Requests;
RequestsTotal = RequestsTotal.Where(rec =>
    rec.RequestTransactions.Last().ServerStatusId != 0);
```

during execute this code , i occurred with an error about using Last Method in Where condition. how i can solve this problem ?!

**UPDATE1** : this is the occured error :

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DAL.RequestTransaction LastRequestTransaction' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

**UPDATE2** : I have a `Request` Table , and this table has an one-to-many relation to `RequestTransactions` table . By this code I tried to fetch all `requests` that **have not** `ServerStatusId = 0` on the last recode of its enter code here `RequestTransactions`.this there any other way ?

Comment: Please can you provide the error that occured.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan, I updated it dude

Comment: Thanks - what's interesting there is that it's moaning about a method that it can't understand, but your code says it's using the `Last()` extension, which should be fine.  Is the `RequestTransactions` member an EF-generated related set?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan , yes both of them are generated as DBset in my EF model

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your Last() method outside of the where:

```
Request newResult =
    RequestsTotal
        .Where(rec => rec.RequestTransactions.ServerStatusId != 0)
        .Last();
```

Last will also execute the query and return a single Request object and not an IQueryable.  So you cannot reuse 'RequestsTotal' for the result.

Comment: actualy i am looking for a solution  to put it out , but i can not :(

Answer (score 0):

I change my code to this way :

```
IQueryable<Request> RequestsTotal = DataContext.Requests;
List<Request> temp = new List<Request>();
foreach (Request request in RequestsTotal)
                {

                    RequestTransaction last = request.RequestTransactions.LastOrDefault();

                    if (last != null && last.ServerStatusId != 0)
                        temp.Add(request);

                }

                RequestsTotal = temp.AsQueryable();
```